# How can I parse Array[Byte] to an HTTP object in Scala

Tags: scala, http

I have a `Array[Byte]` (probably) full of raw HTTP content. Can I use something like [netty HTTPObjectDecoder codec](http://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/handler/codec/http/HttpObjectDecoder.html) to turn the byte array into an HTTP object?

If this isn't clear enough, I have a byte array and I want to turn it into a Scala entity that represents the data in the byte array as an HTTP object (either a request or a response or an error if it's neither one or the other.)

Or are there other better choices than netty? Or some other way to make this work?

Thanks.

Comment: you can use any HTTP client implementation that you want.

Comment: This code example came to me via twitter, but here's how the finagle framework does something similar: https://github.com/twitter/finagle/blob/develop/finagle-base-http/src/main/scala/com/twitter/finagle/http/Request.scala#L241